# Spring Data JPA Projection Collections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How can I get all permissions related to user using projections while keeping projection closed?

User

```
@ElementCollection
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<Permission> permissions;
```

Permission

```java
public enum Permission {
    ADD, UPDATE, DELETE
}
```

UserRepository query

```java
@Query("select u.username as username, p as permissions from User u " 
    + "inner join u.permissions p"
List<UserWithPermissions> findAllProjection();
```

UserWithPermissions projection

```java
public interface UserWithPermissions {
    String getUsername();
    List<Permission> getPermissions();
}
```

Output I want to get

```
User1 : ADD
User2 : ADD DELETE
```

Output I get

```
User1 : ADD
User2 : ADD
User2 : DELETE
```

Comment: looks like you might need a `group by u.username` clause.

Comment: @Alexander then permissions would need to appear in ``GROUP BY``, then it doesn't really do anything. I think, somehow I need to group it in projection, maybe creating another one interface for permissions, which would work as grouping it by user.id, though haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: How your User class looks like? Can you give a code?

Comment: How are you managing Permission, keeping every permission in separate rows or keeping all permissions in single column.

Comment: @AtulSharma separate, just added my user class with permissions field.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your query to

```
@Query("select u from User u")
List<UserWithPermissions> findAllProjection();
```

This should work.

Comment: Query is missing ``join fetch u.permissions``, also this makes projection open, which means it gets all columns and my objective using projections is to select only required columns. Also, permissions seems to be grouped but the output is still 3 different lines, tried using ``distinct`` which made output empty.

Comment: Edit: removing ``@Query`` annotation and fetching permissions with ``@EntityGraph`` i get the output I want, but projection still remains open.